# Uploading image using mongoengine.Imagefield in Djangorest won't save

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am trying to make an image field using mongoengine in DJango. The form shows up, I upload the image, **all other fields are saved except the image** but it keeps saying "This field is required" for the thumbnail_new field. Here is my model

```
class VideoMain(Document):
"""This class represents the Video Meta data model."""
    video_id = fields.SequenceField()
    ytlink = fields.StringField()
    title = fields.StringField()
    description =fields.StringField()
    show = fields.StringField()
    published_at = forms.DateTimeField()
    views = fields.IntField()
    thumbnail = fields.StringField()
    **thumbnail_new = fields.ImageField(size=600,thumbnail_size=None)**
    channel_name = fields.StringField()
    channel_description = fields.StringField()
    guests = fields.ListField(fields.StringField(max_length=30))
    anchors = fields.ListField(fields.StringField(max_length=30))
    tags = fields.ListField(fields.StringField(max_length=30))
```

And here is the Django form

```
from django import forms
from .models import *
class ShowDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    shows = Show.objects.all()
    title = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField()
    channel = forms.CharField()
    publishingdate = forms.CharField()
    views = forms.IntegerField()
    thumbnail = forms.CharField()
    thumbnail_new = forms.ImageField()
    #show = forms.ChoiceField(shows)
    class Meta:
        model = VideoMain
        fields="__all__"
```

And finally the view function where the form has to be stored

```
def show_video_data(request):
"""
View function for renewing a specific BookInstance by librarian"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    #print("I am post")
    form = ShowDetailsForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():         
        newfile=FileUploadHandler(title='anything', file=request.FILES['thumbnail_new'])
        newfile.save()
        print (form.photo)
        # do saving #
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/fetchvideodata')
```

I am new to django, so please bear If there is a silly mistake. I couldn't find a solution or tutorial that uses both mongoengine and django forms. Also I got error while specifying `collection_name="thumbs"`,`**kwargs` in the model `thumbnail_new = fields.ImageField(size=600,thumbnail_size=None)`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem